# nhibernate configuration with x session factories

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm

I am using .net 4.5 with NHibernate 3.3.3.4000 and I want to configurate a nhibernate.config with 2 session-factories.
I tried to configurate my nhibernate.config this way:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory name="Configuration">
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=Configuration.db;Version=3</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <mapping assembly="DataModel"/>
  </session-factory>
  <session-factory name="Texts">
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=Texts.db;Version=3</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <mapping assembly="DataModel_Texts"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

But I get a HibernateConfigException that the "session-factory" is invalid:
An exception occurred parsing configuration :The element 'hibernate-configuration' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2' has invalid child element 'session-factory' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2'.

Do you have an idea how I can configure the file with 2 session factories?

best regards
Phil

Comment: You should be using NH4 with .Net 4.5.

Comment: Is that really the only information you get in the exception AND all it's InnerExceptions, if any?

Comment: Maybe this article can help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14846/Using-NHibernate-with-Multiple-Databases

Comment: I added the inner exeption to the question. 
There is a problem with the name of the session-factory. 
If I delete the second session-factory it's working. Is it allowed to have a second session factory in the same nhibernate.config file? Or do I have to use another config file? 
I will also check the link of Felipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try [NHibernate X-Factories](https://github.com/roydukkey/NHibernate-X-Factories) which provides extension methods for the NHibernate Configure methods. The extension methods allow a name to be specified to select the appropriate session factory from the configuration file.

There is minimal setup, but your configuration file would look something like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration-x-factories xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2-x-factories">
  <session-factory name="Configuration">
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=Configuration.db;Version=3</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <mapping assembly="DataModel"/>
  </session-factory>
  <session-factory name="Texts">
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=Texts.db;Version=3</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <mapping assembly="DataModel_Texts"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration-x-factories>
```

Configuring the session factory could be done in the following way:

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();

config
    .Configure(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/nhibernate.cfg.xml"), "Development")
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Documentation can be found on the [github repo](https://github.com/roydukkey/NHibernate-X-Factories#setup).